# Como faço para conseguir gerar o "apk" da minha aplicação IONIC

Tags: javascript, linux, ionic, apk, build

Seguindo a [**documentação**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html), deveria ser dois comandos simples:

1. Para incluir a plataforma: `ionic platform ios android`
2. Para compilar: `ionic build android`

Porém, estou recebendo um monte de erro em vermelho no terminal, 
conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: tela do erro no terminal linux]

> **Editado até aqui:** Eu resolvi parte do problema, porém, estou com novos erros:

Seguindo as dicas, descompactei o Android JDK na pasta `/usr/local`.

E inclui no final do arquivo `~/.profile` as linhas abaixo:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Depois, executei o comando: `source ~/.profile`

E depois executei os comandos abaixo:

```
 echo >> /.profile
    echo "export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux" >> /.profile
    echo "export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools" >> /.profile
    . /.profile
```

Segui alguns passos através [**desta referência**](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/the-complete-guide-to-running-phonegap-on-ubuntu/):

E agora está exibindo o seguinte erro:

```
➜  TesteApp  ionic build android          
Running command: /var/www/html/apps/TesteApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /var/www/html/apps/TesteApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /var/www/html/apps/TesteApp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: 
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /var/www/html/apps/TesteApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /var/www/html/apps/TesteApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Também executei os comandos para instalar o android-22:

```
cordova platforms remove android
cordova platforms add android@4.1.1
```

E recebi a seguinte mensagem:

```
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.ionicframework.ionicgooglemap340659
    Name: TesteApp
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-22
Copying template files...
Android project created with cordova-android@4.1.1
Running command: /var/www/html/apps/TesteApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /var/www/html/apps/TesteApp
add to body class: platform-android
```

Porém quando executo o comando `ionic build android`, ainda apresenta o mesmo erro.

O que é preciso fazer para que funcione sem erros, eu já tenho o  Java JDK instalado, precisa fazer mais alguma configuração do JAVA?

Comment: Eu recebo os mesmos erros. Tem que ver isso aí.

Comment: Vocês instalaram o Android SDK ?

Comment: Não, precisa instalar?

Comment: Eu não testei com Android ainda. Só iOS.

Comment: Sem dúvida precisa instalar e não tem que definir nenhum path para aplicação, tem que definir o path para sdk.

Comment: Como o @devgaspa disse, precisa do SDK do android e do java.

Comment: Neste [Tutorial em inglês](https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-linux.html) ele ensina a montar o ambiente no linux para somente o cordova então comece a partir do **Install Java** ele ensina a instalar todas as dependências para gerar APK android(**Java**, **Ant** e **Android SDK**). Preste muita atenção e tenha certeza de que está fazendo certo, erros na hora de gerar ambiente de desenvolvimento são terrivelmente terríveis rs.

Comment: @IvanFerrer você instalou estes 3 itens ? 
1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)

Comment: digita android no console, procura API 22 e baixa, ou se preferir pode mudar a versão no arquivo de manifesto na pasta android da aplicação.

Comment: Bom, eu baixei a partir desse link: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz e descompactei.

Comment: esse é o site principal do JDK do Android: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estava usando zsh ao invés do batch.

Consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte, digitei no console:

```
cd ~/

ls -lha

vi .zshrc
```

Incluí a seguinte linhas:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
```

Instalei o Android SDK, e todas as dependências do Java JDK.

No terminal digitei apenas "android" e abriu o Android SDK Manager:

Lá selecionei somente os itens da versão do Android que eu precisava e mandei instalar.
 
Depois executei a linha de comando:

```
 ionic build android
```

E funcionou! ele criou o apk em:

```
/var/www/html/apps/TesteApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/test-app.apk
```